# Downloadable PDF

Tags: wo2003061405a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2003061405A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2003061405A1)

- I would like a printable/ downloadable copy of this patent.  How might I go about this?

Comment: Just to be clear, the cited document is an WO application, not yet a patent.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the word "Espacenet", which is listed as the first of the external links in the google page. You will be navigated at the espacenet platform and then select "original document" (on the left side of the page). Then click "download"!

Comment: Often (not this time) you'll get only one page saying WO/xx2003/xxxxxxx just referencing the prio. doc.

Comment: You mean you get this result in the espacenet platform? I have never encountered this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) . If you go there and enter the application's number you get [this page](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2003_061405_A1) which contains a link to [the pdf](https://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/2003061405/A1/WO_2003_061405_A1.pdf).

The Lens, in my opinion, is much better than Google Patents. For one, it actually finds all the patents relevant to a search which Google Patents has real problems with. Second it is more likely to have the PDF. Lastly it provides better search features, and if you create an account (totally free) you get some nice advantages like saved searches.

Answer (score 0):

For PCT applications and WO publications thereof, I go to the "official" source: PatentScope (one of the links provided in Google Patents).  From there, click on the documents tab, and finally click on one of the multiple specification documents (e.g. "Initial Publication with ISR").